# What is a portable method to find the maximum value of size_t?

Tags: c, size-t

I'd like to know the maximum value of size_t on the system my program is running.
My first instinct was to use negative 1, like so:

```
size_t max_size = (size_t)-1;
```

But I'm guessing there's a better way, or a constant defined somewhere.

Comment: That's one very smart trick you've got there. +1!

Comment: Yep, what you have is fine (you don't need the cast, by the way).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you like to know this?

Comment: @Craig: One possible reason could be to set that as an invalid value for a `size_t` type variable. For instance, `std::string::npos` is set to `(size_t)-1` (at least in the MSVC implementation).

Comment: The way you have done is the best way. `SIZE_MAX` is also available on C99 but not older versions of the standard.

Comment: @Craig: Pretty much what @Praetorian said.

Comment: Can someone explain, what `size_t max_size = (size_t)-1;` actually does and how? Thank you.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type according to the standard. So say it's defined as a 32-bit value. A -1 is represented as 0xffffffff for a signed value using two's complement. However if we cast this to size_t which is an unsigned type, it is the max value instead. `(size_t)(-1)` is the same as `(size_t)(0xffffffff)` on a 32-bit system. It is better to use the -1 since that will work if it's 16-bit (0xffff) or 64-bit as well.

Comment: @Craig Another reason under Posix is converting safely from `off_t` to `size_t`.  `off_t` is aka `long long` for me right now (Xcode 5 on Mavericks) whereas `size_t` is aka `unsigned long` - so I need to range check the `off_t` file size I get back from `fstat` before I can safely cast it to `size_t` and pass it into `mmap`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

A manifest constant (a macro) exists in C99 and it is called `SIZE_MAX`. There's no such constant in C89/90 though.

However, what you have in your original post is a perfectly portable method of finding the maximum value of `size_t`. It is guaranteed to work with any unsigned type.

Comment: Thank you, my compiler needs the cast, or a warning is issued about change of sign during an integer conversion.

Comment: Is it true that's perfectly portable?  What prevents it from being a trap representation?

Comment: @jamesdlin: The signed-to-unsigned conversion is always well-defined in C. It is required to follow the rules of typical unsigned modulo arithmetics with modulo equal to the largest value of the target unsigned type plus 1. So, in the above case you will get `-1 mod (<max-value> + 1)`, which is always just `<max-value>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: §5.2.4.2.1 guarantees that `-1` is representable as an `int`.  §6.3.1.3 guarantees that it converts to a valid `size_t` value.

Comment: @jamesdlin: another way to see that is that `size_t` is an unsigned type, so all values are valid. This can't be a trap representation since there is no such trap.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: That doesn't help, because I don't think it's necessarily true that all N-bit patterns are necessarily valid for an N-bit unsigned type.  However, I do find Stephen's point about §6.3.1.3 compelling since it specifically refers to "the maximal value that can be represented in the new type", which is independent of bit allocation.

Comment: @jamesdlin: yes it does, unsigned types are really simple minded ;-) from "`6.2.6.2 Integer types`": `If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different
power of 2 between 1 and 2^N−1..` So for unsigned integer types there are really no surprises possible.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: You conveniently ignored the part of that section that says: "For unsigned integer types, the bits ... shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits...." Your quote specifically refers to *value bits*.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Yes, but normally you can't create an invalid combination if *padding* bits by doing simple assignment. The danger of producing a trap representation in *padding* bits exists if you "hack" into the object representation through raw memory access, which we are not doing here.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah, I am now in complete agreement that this won't generate a trap representation.  My last couple of comments were solely about the claim that there can be no trap representations for unsigned types.

Answer (score 21):

```
#define MAZ_SZ (~(size_t)0)
```

or `SIZE_MAX`

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative to bit-operations suggested in the other answers, you could do this:

```
#include <limits>
size_t maxvalue = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()
```

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` is not a `constexpr`, and it is not optimized well by some compilers, like Clang. GCC, ICC and MSC handle it fine. Its often better to stick with the `#define`.

Comment: @jww There _should_ be a `constexpr` version of `max()` available: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for being cross-platform, and not using `#define`. And `max()` is `constexpr` in MSVC.

Comment: The question is only tagged C, not C++

Comment: Updated the answer by removing the "in C++" from it, but I'm also fine with removing the answer entirely if that is preferred.

Answer (score 5):

The `size_t max_size = (size_t)-1;` solution suggested by the OP is definitely the best so far, but I did figure out another, more convoluted, way to do this. I'm posting it just for academic curiosity.

```
#include <limits.h>

size_t max_size = ((((size_t)1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(size_t) - 1)) - 1) << 1) + 1;
```

Comment: If I should ever find that in some code (especially without a comment), it would make me very grumpy. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are assuming at least C++11 compiler then SIZE_MAX should be available to you:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits

Comment: The question is only tagged C, not C++ so reference to C++11 is not relevant... but the accepted answer highlights that `sIZE_MAX` is available in C99 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
size_t max_size =  (size_t)-1;
```

I would use:

```
size_t max_size =  size_t(-1);
```

It's just a bit more clear that you constructing a size_t with value -1 and are not subtracting -1 from a hypothetical variable called "size_t" :-D

Comment: Agree, but this is C, and the second is a C++ only cast style.