# What does size_type in the constructor of vector mean?

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, size-type

The specification for the constructor of vector I am using is:

```
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

I am trying to initialize a vector, and I am not very familiar with size_type. Both cplusplus and cppreference don't have an entry for `size_type`. A quick Google tells me it is some kind of data type for representing sizes, capacity etc. for things like containers (I think). I'm still not very sure if I'm understanding it correctly or how to use it though.

Let's say I wish to initialise an `int` vector of count `(10*n/3) + 1` where `n` is of type `int`. Can I cast count as type `long`? Am I even doing it right? How do I understand and use `size_type`?

Please ignore hardware considerations like whether the computer can even assign enough memory in the first place. I'll worry about that later, for now I just want to focus on understanding this concept.

Comment: The [vector member types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Member_types) are there if you just look a little.

Comment: Oh, so that section tells you what the type is? I never understood how to read that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a `typedef` defined inside `std::vector`; it's actually a synonym for `std::size_t`, which, in turn, is a typedef for an implementation-defined unsigned integer type capable of holding the size of the biggest object that is possible to create on the current machine. In practice, you can think of it as some kind of unsigned integer, which is always used throughout the `std::vector` interface when referring to an index or an element count.

On "regular" machines (where you have 32 bit integers) and if you are not hitting the limits of "regular" `int`s in your code for elements counts you can use `int` for indexes without problems (and you are actually safer from subtle bugs that arise from arithmetic/comparisons on unsigned integers).

Comment: "you are actually safer from subtle bugs that arise from arithmetic/comparisons on unsigned integers" Instead of having bugs from unsigned integers you get undefined behaviour from signed integers. Great advice!

Comment: So how can size_type be changed if I wish to accommodate values within the range of a long?

Comment: @dascandy: you get undefined behavior for signed integer overflow if your vector sizes exceed 31 bit, which is highly unlikely in "normal" programs; what happens much more often instead is making calculations with indexes that may result in negative values (which get wrapped around with unsigned integers), or having comparisons between indexes and other `int`s you have around (which get silently "promoted" to `unsigned`). Please, let's stop this `unsigned` indexes bullshit, it hurts way more than the alternative; in a 32 bit world anything which is not a bitfield has no reason to be unsigned.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Perhaps you'd rather make a C++ proposal to make signed integer overflow defined? Then I would not be arguing against you.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - `size_type` is already large enough. It is chosen so that it can hold the largest size a `vector` can ever have.

Comment: @BoPersson is it possible to get the max value of size_t/size_type, and how? So that I can compare and check if the computed value for count is within limits.

Comment: @BoPersson nvm, found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472311/what-is-a-portable-method-to-find-the-maximum-value-of-size-t

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>::size_type` is an unsigned integer type which can represent the size of the largest object in the allocation model. This will often by something like `std::size_t`.

Unless you think you're going to be bumping up against max integral values, you shouldn't need to worry about this; just pass in an integral type and the compiler will tell you if you did something outrageous.

Answer (score 0):

`std::size_t` is a data type, that is large enough to hold the size of any structure that your machine can address. So on 32 bit machines, this is usually a 32 bit unsigned integer.

`T::size_type` is defined by a lot of containers and usually redefines just `std::size_t` (but strictly does not have to). The reason to define it is, that you can just write `T::size_type x = T::your_operation();` without having to think, which container you are using. You can later switch the container and T::size_type still is valid C++ and does not need reworking.